# Unable to execute nightwatch tests on chrome using Linux

Tags: linux, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Here's the bit in question from my nightwatch.json file :

```
 "selenium" : {
   "start_process" : true,
   "server_path" : "lib/selenium-server-standalone.jar",
   "log_path" : "test_logs"
 },

 "test_settings" : {
   "jenkins" : {
     "launch_url" : "url not disclosed",
     "selenium_port"  : 4444,
     "selenium_host"  : "jenkins.undisclosed-cloud.com",
     "cli_args" : {
       "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
     },
     "desiredCapabilities": {
       "browserName": "chrome",
       "javascriptEnabled": true,
       "acceptSslCerts": true,
       "platform" : "LINUX"
     }
   }
 }
```

If I change the browserName to firefox then the test runs fine in the specified linux server, which is running on a **DOCKER CONTAINER**.

But when i choose chrome, i am getting the error:

```
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

I've seen this error before on my local machine and managed to fix it by adding chromedriver to the path. I thought it would be the same issue on this linux server but it did not resolve it. I went on to the linux box and verified I can start the chromedriver directly in

```
"/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
```

By the way I have verified I'm on 64-bit linux machine and the symlinks are all set.

```
Linux version: Linux 3.11.0-26-generic  |  v2.43.1  |  r5163bce
```

ERROR LOG AFTER RUNNING TEST WITH --verbose

```
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session 
 - data:  {"desiredCapabilities":    {"browserName":"chrome","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":    "LINUX","name":"Free Resource Download Test"}} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-    Length":151}
ERROR Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session{ status: 13,
  sessionId: null,
  value: 
   { message: 'chrome not reachable\n
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run the nightwatch tests on a linux (centos) machine. I'm having trouble. I get the error: "Connection refused! Is selenium server started?" What steps did you take to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a docker container and a problem is within Chrome&Docker.

you have 2 options, either run add "--privileged" parameter to a Docker or run Chrome with "--no-sandbox" argument.

Comment: I tried with --no-sandbox but still same issue. this was added as "args" : "--no-sandbox" in the desiredCapability.

Comment: How do i run docker with that --privileged parameter?

Comment: It should be "no-sandbox" without "--" if you are passing it via cli_args (look here https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/wiki/Chrome-Setup). As for docker, look here http://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

Comment: thanks! sorted :) i added   "chromeOptions" : { "args" : ["--no-sandbox"] } to my chrome desired capability and it worked.